# cannot connect to MS FTP 7.5 on Windows 2008 on Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, amazon-ec2, ftp

I have just installed the MS FTP 7.5 upgrade on my Windows 2008 Server (Service Pack 2) running on an Amazon EC2 instance.  In the FTP Firewall Support settings for the server in IIS Manager I have set up the passive port range 45001 - 45005 and also set the External Firewall IP address to match the assigned Amazon Elastic IP address.  Using the AWS Console I changed the Security Group for the server to allow access to the server through ports 21 and 45001 through 45005.  Using an FTP client (either the command line FTP client or Windows Explorer) on the Amazon server I can connect to the FTP server but I cannot connect with an external FTP client.  When I checked to see which ports were open on the server using Shields Up it shows that port 21 is open but ports 45001 to 45005 are closed.

I assume I'm missing something.  Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I just spent several hours trying to figure out this exact problem - only to discover the IP address of the client computer attempting to connect with the EC2 instance was "seen" by IIS 7.5 as the IP address of the Fortigate router/firewall that the client computer is behind.

I had assumed I would enter in the public IP address of the client computer in the Amazon Security Group - but this was not the case. Go figure.

Try opening the Amazon Security settings wide open and check the IIS 7.5 log files to see if this is happening to you too.

Answer (score 1):

late answer but someone else might land in here  . 
Sometimes the FTP server is stuck using the dynamic ports even if you configured a range  . Restart the FTP  and it will pick up the the new values .